# What is the most efficient way to index email addresses in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

What's the best way to index millions of email addresses in MySQL while minimizing the size of the index?

The index is needed to quickly check whether an email exists in the table. Duplicates are allowed.

Again, the goal is to minimize the size of the index. Currently using a standard index on a varchar field, but considering creating a binary hash and indexing the first few characters. Any other options?

Comment: Unique constraint on the email field, if the insert fails - email exists.

Comment: @N.B.: This should be an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Unique Index` for the emails if you don't want any duplicate entry.
If any duplicate entry is done it will not insert any new row and will give error.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that duplicates are allowed. The primary goal is to minimize the index size, though.

Comment: @Justanotherhacker i am not clear about your point if you allow duplicate email then what will you achieve by checking duplicate value for it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Try both and test. Just keep in mind that there is more than read speed in this equation. If this table is heavily updated and inserted then you should see what the effect on inserts are going to be as well.

I suspect (and I could be completely wrong here) that a normal b-tree index will store the value in the tree while a hash index will need to calculate the hash and then store into the tree. This might mean that the hash index uses less space but does more work to get the index updated or new values inserted.

In my mind inserting a new value into the hash index might entail something like

1) Create hash key for value.

2) Insert hash into index.

Where a normal b-tree would be

1) Insert value into index.

Anyway my 2 cents worth.